# Searching for word in table of profanities, all words get flagged

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a database of profanities for a guestbook/comment system in my website.
It allows you to enter, your name, email, message, and my own CAPTCHA thing. Of which the name, message gets publicly displayed, and because of it being public, moderation is important.

I want PHP to proccess the message when it receives it like this:

1. convert message into list of words.
2. Loop through each word in the array and execute a command/function. That command should check if the current word is in the database
3. If it is in the DB `str_replace($bad_word, "[EXPLICIT]", $message)` else go onto next word and repeat

So far I have this code, where `$message` is the users message:

```
$words_in_msg = explode(' ', $message);

        foreach($words_in_msg as &$word) {
            $res = mysqli_query($con,"
                SELECT * FROM `badwords` WHERE `word` = '".$word."'
            ");
            var_dump($res);
            $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
            if ($num !== 0) {
                $message = str_replace($word, "[EXPLICIT]", $message);
            }
        }
```

This code works for the most part, in that it will list all words in `$message`, and it will connect to the DB. But the issue arises **after** executing the SQL command. I have tried using `var_dump($res)` and got a result... but it's not the result I'm looking for. [This](http://pastebin.com/CYZvsjuy) is what I got.

What I actually need to do is simply if the word is in the database replace it.

As a sub-question, is there another more optimized way to execute the same function? I am not sure if this would be too slow considering there are over 1300 words to scan through.

Comment: try using a space between concat operator 
SELECT * FROM `badwords` WHERE `word` = '". $word ."'

Comment: Now sir, you are the god of all gods, i never thought it was so simple. Thank you hugely. If you add that as the answer i can up-vote & accept it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I also hope you don't fall into the [clbuttic](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clbuttic) trap that these sorts of naive substitutions often do.

Comment: Wouldn't `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string)` make the sql command safe? Or am i missing something

Comment: @Salamander115: escaping has been known to suffer bugs due to character set issues. It is normally fine, but parameterisation - where the engine knows the difference between query and value - is still safer.

Comment: Did you mean [EXPLETIVE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space between the concat operators in your sql query, so instead of

```
SELECT * FROM `badwords` WHERE `word` = '".$word."
```

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM badwords WHERE word = '". $word ."
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to accept the answer for 7 minutes so, I'm sorry but you have to wait till then :)

Comment: @Salamander115 that's not an issue :) let me know if you have any other query

Comment: Sorry to bug you but i do, a little. Is there any way to, instead of replacing it with `[EXPLICIT]` replace it with `*`s for example `hello` would become `h***o` or `h****` or something like that.

Comment: @Salamander115 yes you can use 
substr_replace($word,"****",1,strlen($word)-1);

Comment: And if you wanna display last character than use
substr_replace($word,"****",1,-1);

Comment: omg! I received a vote down for this answer. Who is retarded over here

Answer (score 2):

I have some tips for how to optimize this:

1. Use array_unique to limit the number of words to check: `$words_in_msg = array_unique(explode(' ', $message));`
2. Only run your query once, then get an array of all the bad words. So, move it outside of the loop.
3. Before looping through the array of words first do an [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). If the resulting array is empty you can stop there since there are no bad words.
4. If there are bad words, you can use your current loop, but instead of running a query each time use:

   foreach($words_in_msg as $word) {
     if( in_array($word, $aryBadWords){
       $message = str_replace($word, "[EXPLICIT]", $message);
     }
   }

Alternately, you could use a single regular expression to perform all the substitutions

```
$regex = '/(' . implode('|', $words_in_msg) . ')/i';
$message = preg_replace($regex, '[EXPLICIT]', $message);
```

Not running the query for every word would be a big improvement.

Comment: Instead of N substitutions, a singular regular expression is often significantly faster.

Comment: I thought of that, but is it feasible if the message has 100+ words?

Comment: A properly constructed regular expression requires one replacement vs. one string, and even really complicated regular expressions usually run in near zero time. Otherwise you're dealing with M words times N substitutions which will quickly become geometrically huge.